# How do I get the value of a string variable from a JSONParser class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-json, android-async-http

I have a log-in web API which returns true if you have successfully logged-in and false otherwise.

Now I want to get that returned value which is why I have made used of this `PostAsync` Class calling on an `HttpRequest` Method from the `JSONParser` Class.

**These are the codes:**

```
public class Sign_inFragment extends Fragment {

    String email, password, logInResult;
    EditText ev, pv;
    Button bv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_fragment, container, false);

        bv = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.signinButton);
        ev = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        pv = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.passwordTextView);

        bv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ev.getText() != null && pv.getText() != null) {
                    email = ev.getText().toString();
                    password = pv.getText().toString();

                    new PostAsync().execute(email, password);

                    //logInResult = //Get the value from the API which should return true or false
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://my-api.mydoctorfinder.com/logger";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


    /*@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", args[0]);
            params.put("password", args[1]);

            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        int success = 0;
        String message = "";

        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (json != null) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(),
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Success!", message);
        }else{
            Log.d("Failure", message);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class JSONParser {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;
    String logInResult;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

            logInResult = result.toString();//I want to get the value of this String variable.

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following solutions:

Make the async task doInBackground method return an object of your desire and inside the doInBackground parse your json and save some values inside this object.

Then in onPostExecute you get the object and return it to the caller(activity, fragment, etc) via a callback. 
Solution two, just return the desired string in doInBackground and get it in onPostExecute and do the same as I said in the first solution.
Example for the object(same goes for string):

```
 @Override
protected CustomObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    CustomObject customObject = null;
    try {

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", args[0]);
        params.put("password", args[1]);

        Log.d("request", "starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

        if (json != null) {
            Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

           //parse your json;
           //for example:
           customObject = parseCustomObject(json);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return customObject;
}
```

Comment: Wherein you still have to use an interface to pass the object back to the calling class. I see....

Comment: Wait, where did you get the parseCustomObject method?

Comment: You have to implement it yourself. it is pseudocode, not working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add interface in your AsyncTask class for add Listener like below:

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener {
    public void asyncTaskComplted(String result);

}
```

and than after got success in onPostExecute method pass the result string as:

```
mAsyncTaskCompleteListener.asyncTaskComplted(message);
```

You can pass listener object into your Async's constructor. check below:

```
public PostAsync(AsyncTaskCompleteListener  mAsyncTaskCompleteListener){
    this.mAsyncTaskCompleteListener=mAsyncTaskCompleteListener;
}
```

And call this in your fragment like:

```
new PostAsync(new PostAsync.AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void asyncTaskComplted(String result) {
            Log.print("Result string :  "+result);
        }
    }).execute(email, password);
```

Comment: One more thing, how do you get that message into the Fragment class where it started? I'd love to see a sample code on how to handle that message.

Comment: @Chris i have updated my answer. One more thing i noted in your code is in case of false response its throw JSONException that Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject. You need to handle that before converted into JSONObject.